# Dynamic HTML to PDF using Python or Javascript

Tags: javascript, django, html2canvas, html2pdf, xhtml2pdf

I am trying to add "Download PDF" link on my webapp. At the moment, I call a django function which gets a queryset and passes the context to a html file.
However, I would like users to be able to download this html file as a pdf with watermark in the center.

I have tried jspdf html2canvas but nothing works with. I have tried xhtmlpdf but its too slow in rendering the html. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the question? Asking for a fast and reliable HTML to PDF converter?

Comment: In a way yes, my platform offers quizzes to students and they should be able to download it for practising offline with MCQ/Images and Watermark. This should have page breaks , mathematical equations using Latex , etc. I am able to generate my html.  My original question was unanswered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66628560/download-dynamic-html-with-images-as-pdf-with-watermark-using-django-python

Comment: But, but ... That's [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for SO. You can ask software recommedations at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: But not exactly, I need a solution a python library or javascript plugin :)

Answer (score 0):

`wkhtmltopdf` is probably the fastest you are going to get. It is using QT Webkit under the hood, so you can't ask for much more than that ([homepage](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/index.html) [github](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf)).

I see that there is a library of python bindings [here](https://pypi.org/project/wkhtmltopdf/), but it is not maintained anymore. Since performance is your utmost concern, if you *just* need html => pdf, I can't imagine the C-to-python binding being more than 100 lines of code, most of which would be boilerplate. However, calling the CLI with python's `subprocess` module should be very fast too. Since it would be so easy to set up, I'd probably start with that, profile it, and see how it suits your use case.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you look at Weasyprint.  I use it to render PDFs with watermarks (via simple css).  No built in Latex/javascript support, though, so you'd need a way to convert your equations into svg files.

Comment: installing it is a nightmare. Thanks